# Write array of struct using TwinCAT.Ads through vb.net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I’m using TwinCAT.Ads (TwinCAT 3) for Beckhoff plc communication through vb.net application. Application is reading and writing few plc variables.
I need to write in an array of struct.

My struct :

```
Friend Structure Struct_Recette
    Dim nNumProg As Integer             ' Programme associated
    Dim nNumZone As Integer             ' Zone
    Dim nNumManifold As Integer         ' Manifold
    Dim nNumRallonge As Integer         ' Rallonge
    Dim nNumSaphir As Integer           ' Saphir
    Dim nNumMors As Integer             ' Mors
End Structure
```

My Plc :

```
valTabRecette:      ARRAY [0..15] OF Struct_Recette;
```

My Code :

```
Friend Sub ValidationMPodeProd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnValidProd.Click
    Dim valTabRecette(0 To 15) As Struct_Recette

    'Some code to fill the structs

        ADS.WriteAny(PLCHandle, valTabRecette)
    End If
End Sub
```

I Have the error when I launch this :

```
0x705 parameter size not correct
```

**I resolve the problem :**
The type are not the same in vb.net and Beckhoff

```
vb.net          Beckhoff 
int        =      Dint
short      =      int
```

....etc

So the parameters of my struct had not the good type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference for those who are having similar problems:
The difference in data type for TwinCAT and VB can be found in Beckhoff website:
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcsystemmanager/basics/TcSysMgr_DatatypeComparison.htm&id=

TwinCAT is using IEC61131-3 standard.